# Fill a second selectlist dependend on the data selected in first selectlist

Tags: java, jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working on a project in java ( spring boot ). We use the framework thymeleaf aswell in our project.
Now I have encountered a problem:

I have 2 select lists above eachother. When I select an item in the first list, I want the second select list to be filled with the items related to that selected item. How do I do this ? Note: the data inside of the first select list comes from my controller, I am also passing the data that has to be filled in in the second select list, but this information still has to be filtered depending on the first select list.

To give you guys a background story. The first select list contains all the customers, when a customer is selected the second select list has to be filled with all the projects that customer has.

*Now the code*

The view:

```
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Generate invoice</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<label>What customer do you want to create an invoice from ?</label>
<!--Dropdown projects-->
<div>
<div id="dropdowncontracts">
<select class="selectpicker" id="picker">
<option selected disabled>Select a customer</option>
<option value="all">all customers</option>
<option th:each="customer : ${customers}" th:text="${customer.name}"/>
</select>
</div>
<div id="hiddenClient">
<label style="position: absolute">What contract ?</label>
<select class="selectpicker" style="float: left; position: relative; margin-left: 0px;">
<option selected disabled>select a contract</option>
<option>all contracts</option>
<option>contract 1</option>
<option>contract 2</option>
<option>contract 3</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
@GetMapping
@Secured(Roles.FINANCIAL)
public String getInvoices(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("invoice", service.getInvoices());
    model.addAttribute("customers",customerService.getCustomers());
    model.addAttribute("projects",projectService.getProjects());
    return INVOICE_LIST_PATH;
}
```

If you need something else, please don't hesitate to ask !
Thanks in advance

Edit 1:

Thanks a lot for the answer Ashutosh, but because of bootstrap select list I still have a problem.
Bootstrap creates the select lists at runtime so when I fill the select lists, bootstrap has already created the "good looking" lists at runtime. See code below:

[inspector overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUHt6.png)

**Solved my own question**

Just needed an .selectpicker('refresh') after filling my selectlist.

Thanks for the help everyone !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class HomeController {

    private final List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>(3);
    private final Map<String, List<Project>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(3);

    public HomeController() {
        // initialize the list and map
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            final Customer c = new Customer("customer-" + i);
            customers.add(c);
            final List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>(3);
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                final Project p = new Project("project-" + i + "" + j);
                projects.add(p);
            }
            map.put(c.getName(), projects);
        }

    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        log.info("customers : {}", customers);
        model.addAttribute("customers", customers);
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    public @ResponseBody List<Project> index(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        final List<Project> projects = map.get(name);
        log.info("projects : {}", projects);
        return projects;
    }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#selectCustomer").change(function (event) {
        fire_ajax();
    });

});

function fire_ajax() {

    var name = $("#selectCustomer").val();
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/"+name,
        dataType:'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {
    var options = "<option selected disabled>select a project</option>"
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
     options += "<option value=\""+value.name+"\">"+value.name+" </option>"
   });
                   
            $('#selectProject').html(options);
            console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="customers">
    <label>Customer</label> 
    <br/>
    <select class="selectCustomer" id="selectCustomer">
     <option selected disabled>Select a customer</option>
     <option th:each="customer : ${customers}"
      th:value="${customer.name}" th:text="${customer.name}" />
    </select>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div id="projects">
    <label>What project ?</label> 
    <br/>
    <select class="selectProject" id="selectProject">
     <option selected disabled>select a project</option>
    </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! But I still encounter a problem because of when you insert the options inside of your ajax call into the select list, they appear when I view the source inside of the inspector, but I also work with bootstrap so bootstrap generates the options at runtime. I will make an edit of this post because I can't find how to post code inside this comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the if statement in thymeleaf like this for exemple

```
<div th:if="${condition}> 
<select  th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence( 1, 81/20)}>
   <option th:text="${ i }"></option>
</select>
</div>
```